# MYSQL regex query to retrive IP Range

Tags: mysql, regex

Hello I have something new assignment. I have a table IPsource which stores IP ranges. For instance

```
IPRange(columnType -- VarChar) 
10.25.23.[1-36]
10.25.23.[70-198]
47.26.23.[1-255]
```

Mysql query input would be this

```
select * from IPsource where IPRange= '10.25.23.32'
```

then it should select record `10.25.23.[1-36]`

Any help highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use `RLIKE` :

```
SELECT * FROM IPsource WHERE IPRange RLIKE '^10\\.25\\.23\\.(([0-2]*[1-9]*)|(3[1-6]))$'
```

- take a look at [MySQL Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)
- take a look at [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pOtJ9q/1)
- take a look at [MySQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf3df/1)

Comment: Hello @YCF_L : The above snippet works on individual IPs present in DB, but not on IPRange.  Ref# http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73b010c/1.

Comment: @Hamer307 what did you mean you want to match `10.25.23.[1-27]` `10.25.23.[1-30]` or what exactly?

Comment: What ever IP address I give in mySQL query, it has to check and match the IPRange stored in table. Hope I am clear..

Comment: mmm, this is not possible @Hamer307 because the regex of each range is deffirent of the other

Comment: Thankyou @YCF_L, is there any other way that we can perform this action? or if if IP has single range is that possible say 10.25.23.[0-255] ? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Hamer307 to match this range you can use [`^10\.25\.23\.([0-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$`](https://regex101.com/r/W817O0/1) hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring_index instead of regex. This will return 1, 1, 0, 0:

```
select
substring_index('12.34.56.78', '.', 1) between 10 and 13,
substring_index(substring_index('12.34.56.78', '.', 2), '.', -1) between 30 and 34,
substring_index(substring_index('12.34.56.78', '.', 3), '.', -1) between 50 and 51,
substring_index(substring_index('12.34.56.78', '.', 4), '.', -1) between 10 and 20
```

I know it's not regex but may be usefull for someone so I decided to paste it here :)

Comment: Thankyou for your time ElChupacabra. If not regular expression I have to find another way to get the desired output.